# how to find the users location when you are having longitude and latitude?

Tags: ios

I want to find the location from the given latitiude and longitude. problem is in my app i have to find more than 20 users locations at a time and the long,lat data is getting from services and my task is to get the location from longitude and latitudes...

Answer (score 1):

Use Reverse GeoCoding of iOS. There is a `CLGeocoder` class from  **Mapkit Framework** and it uses `reverseGeocodeLocation` method to retrieve user's actual location from latitude and longitude.

```
- (void)reverseGeocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)location completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler
```

This method takes two parameters:

**location** : Use your latitude and longitude to create a `CLLocation` object and pass that object on to this method.
This is how you can achieve in creating a `CLLocation` object.

```
 CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:_yourLatitude longitude:_yourLongitude];
```

**completionHandler**: This is a block object that gets executed when the reverse geocoding is successful.

You can have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/geocoder-reverse-geocoder-tutorial-for-ios-using-mapkit/).

Comment: why reverse geocoder give accurate location compare with gogle api

Comment: I don't think that is the case always. Sometimes the results are not that accurate. The thing to understand is that CLGeocoder object also uses the Internet/or the webservices to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

pass your latitude and longitude values in this url.

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=true",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    annotation.tag = 0;
    //SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    if([[dict valueForKey:@"results"] count]>0)
        NSString *location = [[[dict valueForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"formatted_address"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

Pass the values to this reverseGeocodeLocation handler.
[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder)

Comment: CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:Latitude longitude:Longitude];

Answer (score 0):

You should know about the process first. This is called Geocoding.
You have 2 types of geocoding, forward and reverse gecoding. You can get the address from latitude-longitude and latitude-longitude from an address.
You should go with some tutorials. Here are some links.

[Forward and Reverse Geocoding](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/geocoder-reverse-geocoder-tutorial-for-ios-using-mapkit/)

[Forward and Reverse Geocoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html)

You can also use the google API for geocoding, which provides the best results..

Cheers
Sanjay